# Partitioning Table Error with more partitions than Filegroups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to partition a DB table, I have created the filegroups correctly (I think), I had to add a couple of extra filegroups along the way as I had an error with the amount of partitions compared to filegroups (I have trouble getting my head round this), I have created a partition function without problem, but when I try to create the partition scheme I get the following error:

> Msg 7707, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The associated partition function
>   'PARTFN_INV_LINE_FACT' generates more
>   partitions than there are file groups
>   mentioned in the scheme
>   'PARTSCH_INV_LINE_FACT'.

Have I missed a step?

I am new and doing this to learn for a future task, so please excuse me if I haven’t given enough information. I have included everything I have done below.

All filegroups have to be explicitly entered in the scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All filegroups have to be explicitly entered in the scheme.

Answer (score 8):

Without seeing the code, I can't be 100% sure, but I suspect you've run into the exact problem I did when I tried to reuse a current partition function with a new partition scheme. My partition function defined 16 range values, however my partition scheme only defined 8 partitions, resulting in the same error you've cited.

In my case, the solution was to simply not try to reuse the existing partition function, and instead create a new partition function and partition scheme, with an equal number of range values and partitions like this:

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION partitionFunctionName(datetime)
AS
RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (
                       '20130228 23:59:59.997',
                       '20130331 23:59:59.997',
                       '20130430 23:59:59.997',
                       '20130531 23:59:59.997',
                       '20130630 23:59:59.997',
                       '20130731 23:59:59.997',
                       '20130831 23:59:59.997',
                       '20130930 23:59:59.997'
                       )
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [partitionSchemeName]
AS
PARTITION partitionFunctionName TO
   (
       [PartitioningFileGroupName1]
      ,[PartitioningFileGroupName2]
      ,[PartitioningFileGroupName3]
      ,[PartitioningFileGroupName4]
      ,[PartitioningFileGroupName5]
      ,[PartitioningFileGroupName6]
      ,[PartitioningFileGroupName7]
      ,[PartitioningFileGroupName8]
      ,[PRIMARY]
   )

GO

I know this is an old question, but maybe this will help someone avoid the same issue!

Comment: Thanks for mention about the default partition!

Answer (score 6):

Probably you forgot to include the [PRIMARY] filegroup in your partition scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The number of criteria must be missing a number of filegroups, partition functions.

Answer (score 1):

you have to match the filegroups.

SELECT name AS AvailableFilegroups
FROM sys.filegroups
WHERE type = 'FG'

The result of the query should be equal to the scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Have you mentioned the filegroups which are available in your system?

You may get filegroup list from the query:

```
SELECT name AS AvailableFilegroups
  FROM sys.filegroups
  WHERE type = 'FG'
```

Answer (score 1):

Also I faced the same error: **The number of filegroups or range values is not valid. Enter an extra filegroup in addition to the number of boundary values.** I just added a filegroup for the **last empty row**.

[image]