Problem with partitioning and foreign keys
I encountered an issue while adding partitioning to Table1.
Previously, this table had a primary key consisting only of the Id column, but when I added partitioning, I had to include AddTimestamp in the composite key. Now I want to change the structure so that the primary key consists only of Id again, but this leads to errors when trying to create a foreign key in Table2.
Problem description:

Partitioning: I created a partition function and partition scheme to split the data by timestamps:

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_AddTimestamp (DATETIMEOFFSET(7))
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (
    '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    '2021-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    '2023-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    '2024-01-01T00:00:00Z'
);

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_AddTimestamp
AS PARTITION PF_AddTimestamp
TO ([PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY]);


Creating Table1: I created the table with partitioning and a composite primary key:

CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    AddTimestamp DATETIMEOFFSET(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),
    SomeField1 VARCHAR(100),
    SomeField2 INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY (Id, AddTimestamp)
)
ON PS_AddTimestamp (AddTimestamp);

However, when I tried to change the primary key to consist only of Id, I encountered the following error:

The associated partition function 'PF_AddTimestamp' generates more partitions than there are file groups mentioned in the scheme 'PS_AddTimestamp'


Creating Table2: I created Table2 with a foreign key referencing Id from Table1:

CREATE TABLE Table2 
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Table1Id INT,
    SomeField3 VARCHAR(100),
    SomeField4 DECIMAL(10, 2),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1 
        FOREIGN KEY (Table1Id) REFERENCES Table1(Id)
);

But when creating the foreign key, I get the following error:

There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Table1' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Table2_Table1'.

I want the primary key in Table1 to consist only of Id, so that I can successfully create a foreign key in Table2 that references Table1 (Id).
How can I resolve this issue?
I would appreciate any advice or recommendations regarding this issue!

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384560/partitioning-table-error-with-more-partitions-than-filegroups

What's the script you're running when you get: However, when I tried to change the primary key to consist only of Id, I encountered the following error:


How can I resolve this issue?

Once you make ID the PK you won't have any trouble adding the foreign key.  You will have to change the partitioning.  You can still partition by ID if you want.
Or you could have one column that is both the PK and the timestamp, eg Generate a unique time-based id on a table in SQL Server
